# Python AES encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to get a python program that decrypts some Base64-encoded, encrypted using AES-128 in ECB mode, text.

So, I am using this tutorial: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/crypto/ to get started.

It contains this code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
# Encryption
encryption_suite = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
cipher_text = encryption_suite.encrypt("A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")

# Decryption
decryption_suite = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
plain_text = decryption_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
```

I have copied the code into a aes_2.py file. And, I have run it using: `sudo python3 aes_2.py`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aes_2.py", line 21, in <module>
    cipher_text = encryption_suite.encrypt("A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 244, in encrypt
    return self._cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
```

**EDIT 1**

I have a file that I was told to decrypt. I was given a key and the file and some specs on the decryption. This site decrypts it: http://aesencryption.net/ when I enter the key, 128 Bit, and the text into the site.

For this code above. I have a couple questions. What should I put for `'This is an IV456'` and how do I specify what Bit level it is in this code?

Comment: @Arman you are right, I added a few characters and it ran. Odd, I didn't change the tutorial at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `AES.MODE_CBC` which means that your input string i.e. `'This is a key123'` must be a multiple of 16 bytes.

If you want to continue using this mode then you will need to pad your string. This [git repo](https://gist.github.com/crmccreary/5610068) is a great example of AES encryption using padding in CBC mode.